# Is there a way to make PDF generation async with PDFMake?

Tags: node.js, performance, pdfkit, pdfmake

I have an API for pdf generation and I'm using pdfmake for this.
Some files take a long time to generate (1 second) and if I have several concurrent request, the response time increases.
For the generation I've tried this

```
 let generatePdf = function generate(data){

  return new Promise(function ( resolve, reject) {
    
    try {
    
      let printer = new PdfPrinter(FONTS);
      let reporte = new ReporteCompVenta(data,'A4');

      let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(reporte.generar(), {});
      
      pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("files/"+randomstring.generate(5) + '.pdf')
        .on("error", (err) => {
          reject(err.message);
        }) 
      );
      
      pdfDoc.on('end', () => {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve("this is a test"); }, 30000);
      });
  
      pdfDoc.end();
  
    } catch(err) {
      throw(err);
    }
  }) ; 

}
```

Is it possible to make printer.createPdfKitDocument async or not blocking?